# Django Send Email Error: ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, email, django-3.2

I was trying to send an email via Django using the `send_mail()` function from `django.core.mail` when I ran into this error:

`ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused`

This is my code, straight from the docs:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail(
    'Subject here',
    'Here is the message.',
    'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

I replaced `from@example.com` with one of email IDs and I replace `to@example.com` with one of my other email IDs.

When I run `runserver`, I get this peculiar error

```
$ python3 manage.py runserver

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/adithraghav/Documents/Work/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/adithraghav/Documents/Work/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Users/adithraghav/Documents/Work/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 419, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/Users/adithraghav/Documents/Work/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/Users/adithraghav/Documents/Work/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "/Users/adithraghav/Documents/Work/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "/Users/adithraghav/Documents/Work/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/adithraghav/Documents/Work/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 598, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/adithraghav/Documents/Work/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/adithraghav/Documents/Work/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 591, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/adithraghav/Documents/Work/freekode/freekode/urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    from users import views as user_views
  File "/Users/adithraghav/Documents/Work/freekode/users/views.py", line 7, in <module>
    send_mail(
  File "/Users/adithraghav/Documents/Work/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 61, in send_mail
    return mail.send()
  File "/Users/adithraghav/Documents/Work/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 284, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/Users/adithraghav/Documents/Work/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 102, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/Users/adithraghav/Documents/Work/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 62, in open
    self.connection = self.connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 253, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 339, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 310, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 843, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 831, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

I am using `Django 3.2` and `Python 3.9.2`.
I'd really appreciate some help.